# Bolt Repeating Route

Tags: php, silex, bolt-cms

Is it possible to have a repeating route in the bolt cms? I made a route in my routing.yml that looks like this

```
language:
    path: /{locale}/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: controller.frontend:template, template: 'page.twig' }
```

It renders the page.twig using the template function on the Frontend controller. So when I dump the variables in my page.twig in this way

```
{{ dump(app.request.get('locale')) }}
{{ dump(app.request.get('slug')) }}
```

This will output.

```
"en"
"stackoverflow"
```

But I want a repeating route that would work like this.

```
language:
    path: /{locale}/{slug**}
    defaults: { _controller: controller.frontend:template, template: 'page.twig' }
```

So when I access an url like:

```
bolt.dev/en/slug1/slug2
```

I will receive a array in my view named slug and it will output

```
[slug1, slug2]
```

Comment: Don't use screenshot to inject your source. It's not search able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bolt uses Symfony routing under the hood, and there isn't a concept of array parameters.

What you can do is capture the entire url after your locale and then split it in Twig, so:

```
language:
    path: /{locale}/{slug}
    defaults: 
        _controller: controller.frontend:template
        template: 'page.twig'
    requirements:
        slug: .+
```

This allows the slash to be captured as part of slug, so assuming your url is `/en/slug1/slug2` then doing `app.request.get('slug')` will return `slug1/slug2` which you can then split in Twig:

```
{% for slug in app.request.get('slug')|split('/') %}
    {{ slug }}
{% endfor %}
```